# An observable stream that will emit a value twice

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a situation where I need an observable to emit two values. The first value should be emitted immediately and all subscribers should get the value immediately. The second value may take some time, but all subscribers should get that value as well.

Current I achieve it doing this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {tap, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class CacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const cachedResponse = cache.get(req);
        const results$ = sendRequest(req, next);
        return cachedResponse ? results$.pipe(startWith(cachedResponse)) : results$;
    }
}

function sendRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        tap(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                cache.put(req, event);
            }
        })
    );
}

export class HttpCache {
    cache = new Map();

    get(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpResponse<any> | undefined {
        // ...
    }

    put(req: HttpRequest<any>, response: HttpResponse<any>): void {
        // ...
    }
}

const cache: HttpCache = new HttpCache();
```

As you can see, I attempt to do `results$.pipe(startWith(cachedResponse))`.

It seems that that what happens is I always get the `results$` value emitted, and the `cachedResponse` value is never emitted. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you have seems fine to me. Are you sure `cachedResponse` contains anything?